# How to import millions of records from SQL Server 2000 to Microsoft Excel 2010

Tags: sql-server, database, excel, import

I have around 3.5 million records that i want to import into a Excel 2010 file. I have tried using SQL Servers Import/Export Data Wizard and this worked but the problem was that it only copied about 65,000 out of the 3,500,000 records i need. This is due to a limit that is on Excel.

I have tried to install PowerPivot to try increase the amount of records that could be inserted into excel but with no luck. Does anyone know how i would do this?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I need to do it for comparing records with another source. All the records do not necessarily all have to be in the same excel file (can be split to numerous files) but they have to be in excel files

Comment: try exporting to CSV then opening the csv in excel

Comment: 3.5M records in Excel?  If you cannot do it in your SQL data base, have you considered using Access for your comparisions?  You might not even have to import the SQL data, since Access can use a SQL data base table as a linked table.  Importing your other sources into Access should be easier that making a huge Excel file.

Comment: Excel?  Bad Idea Jeans.  Yeah, I like the Jet/Access idea over Excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this thanks to jsobo's comment above.

I first created a blank .csv file. Then i was able to use SQL Servers DTS Import/Export Wizard to add all the fields straight from the database to the .csv file